# Detach root volume of ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hardware

I am using a spot instance to do some work and to preserve the data, I am remounting a previously existing volume as the root volume of my current instance. So the root volume that the instance started with is no longer in use and I wanted to remove it to save costs.

I have unmounted the previous root volume and tried detaching it from the cli with and without the --force param and both ends in failure with this error :

```
An error occurred (IncorrectState) when calling the DetachVolume operation: Unable to detach root volume
```

I realize that this would be because aws mounts the initial root in xv/s da1 and aws prevents me from detaching it.

Are there any steps that I can follow to detach the unmounted root volume ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't.  Detaching the root volume requires that the instance be stopped, and spot instances can't be stopped.

> to preserve the data, I am remounting a previously existing volume as the root volume of my current instance.

That's not really the correct thing to be doing.  Spot instances are inherently ephemeral, and reusing the root volume is not an intended action.

Using Elastic File System, if it is available in your region, is ideal for this.  An EFS filesystem mounts into your hierarchy wherever you need it, someplace like `/srv/data` for example, and these can also be mounted simultaneously to multiple instances.

S3 can also be used, though your code has to be written with this in mind.

Alternately, save your work on an EBS volume that isn't the root volume if you want to move volumes around.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I have to reuse the root volume, I am building a few libraries which take >45 mins to build and I don't want to rebuild them each time, I start to do something. I have to install a few libraries in the standard /usr/lib etc locations to get the lib to build.I guess if I keep using the same ami and build the lib in a separate file system it might work.

Comment: No, no... build the machine the way you want it, make a custom AMI of the machine, and launch your future spot instances from the custom AMI.  All of your libraries will be there, on a freshly cloned copy of your custom root volume each time the spot machine starts up.

Comment: Why didn't I think about that. :) Can I create an AMI from the data that I stored too? So each time, I want to shut down the instance, create an AMI, which will store all the data + libs, then start a new instance from that AMI ? Is that possible ? Does aws charge for creating an AMI. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Everything on the machine's EBS volumes at the time you create the AMI will be there each time you launch from the AMI.  AMIs are free, but you're billed EBS Snapshot Storage charges for the snapshots that back them.

Comment: @sqlbot. Thanks!

Comment: Remember if you delete an AMI to delete the snapshot(s), as well.  There will be a snapshot for each EBS volume.

Comment: You can now stop ec2 spot instances https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/amazon-ec2-spot-can-now-stop-and-start-your-spot-instances/#:~:text=To%20use%20this%20new%20feature,saved%2C%20and%20their%20data%20persists. Remember that!